# Generate recursive object list in C#

Tags: c#

I have class models like below :

```
public class ABC
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public List<ABC> children { get; set; }
}
```

And structure data like this

```
Parent   Value
  1       A
  A       C
  2       B
  B       D
```

I would like to recursively build an complex object. I have managed to recursively add Children to children.
How can I return `List<ABC>` like results below ?

```
[
  {
    value: '1',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'A',
        children: [
          {
            value: 'C',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    value: '2',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'B',
        children: [
          {
            value: 'D',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: You mean you want to serialize it, with say newtonsoft `JsonConvert.SerializeObject( obj,  Formatting.Indented)` It wouldn't match perfectly, because the `obj` would have to be an array or a list of ABC itself to return it correctly

Answer (score 0):

This sample output what you expect, with more children.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;

public class Json
    {
        public class ABC
        {
            public string value { get; set; }
            public List<ABC> children { get; set; }
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            var abcs = new List<ABC>();
            abcs.Add(new ABC()
            {
                value = "1",
                children = new List<ABC>()
                {
                    new ABC() { value = "A", children = new List<ABC>() {
                        new ABC() { value = "C" }
                    }},
                    new ABC() { value = "F" }
                }
            });

            abcs.Add(new ABC()
            {
                value = "2",
                children = new List<ABC>()
                {
                    new ABC() { value = "B", children = new List<ABC>() {
                        new ABC() { value = "D" }
                    }},
                    new ABC() { value = "G" }
                }
            });

            var ser = JsonSerializer.Serialize(abcs, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true, DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull });
            Console.WriteLine(ser);
        }
    }
```